# Why does this C# function to draw a sine wave using System.Drawing overflows?

Tags: c#, winforms, graph, drawing, trigonometry

So I made this little windows forms program that draws a sine wave but when I put certain functions like `sin(x) ^ x` it overflows.
Please review this code and help me figure this out!

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Completed) return;
        Completed = true;
        Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
        Pen pen = new Pen(Brushes.Black, 2.0F);

        float x1 = 0;
        float y1 = 0;

        float y2 = 0;

        float yEx = 300;
        float eF = 50;


        for (float x = 0; x < Width; x += 0.005F)
        {
            y2 = (float)Math.Pow(Math.Sin(x) , x);

            g.DrawLine(pen, x1 * eF, y1 * eF + yEx, x * eF, y2 * eF + yEx);
            x1 = x;
            y1 = y2;
        }

    }
```

When I execute, it runs for a bit and then displays this:
[image: what is exactly displayed]

Any contribution is appreciated!

Comment: The maximum value for a `float` is the same as `Int32`.  If the result is greater than 2,147,483,647 than you'll get the overflow error.  Have you tried using `double` (which is the same maximum value as `Int64` -  9,223,372,036,854,775,807)?  Or do checks on the values to handle the overflows.

Comment: You're not validating your inputs into the pen. You should make sure they are within the bounds of the canvas because it doesn't really like drawing into nothing.

Comment: So what is the value of `Width`? Dropping this into Visual Studio and using a value like 1920 then printing `y2` gives me a lot of results (many of them `NaN`), but I never get an overflow. And that makes sense, really - the range of `sin(x)^x` is going to be restricted to (-1, 1), so that should never overflow.

Comment: the first number that fails is `sin(3.15002465)^3.15002465` which results in [complex number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number). @Abion47 math is not that easy I guess ;) https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin(3.15002465)%5E3.15002465

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary It never is... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, so it turns out the solution is a mix of TyCobb's answer and John Wu's answer. When you use `Math.Sin` on an increasing value like `x`, roughly half of the output from `Math.Sin(x)` is going to be negative. `Math.Pow` doesn't like it when you give it a negative number in the first parameter and a non-integer as the second parameter (it will return `NaN` in this case). The reason for this is because when you raise a negative number by a non-integer, the result is a complex number.

Now `Graphics.DrawLine` doesn't care if you pass `NaN` as either of the second pair of `float` parameters (`x2, y2`) as it will just return without doing anything. But if you pass `NaN` as one of the first pair (`x1, y1`), it will throw an `OverflowException`. Why it does this, I'm not sure, but I'd be willing to guess that it was an oversight on the part of the .NET team back in the day.

Now from the first discovery, you can see the problem is mainly whenever `x` is negative. The easy solution to that would be to replace `x` with `Math.Pow(x)`, but that might alter the output in a way that doesn't reflect the intentions of the original function. A second solution would be to simply skip those iterations, but that will leave holes in your graph.

A third solution you may have guessed already, but that is to replace `Math.Pow` with `Complex.Pow`. This will give you the support you need for the potential inputs you may get to your power function by returning a complex number. Once you've done that, you can choose what you want to do with the result. (I just took the `Real` part of the result as my `y` and discarded the `Imaginary` portion.)

```
for (float x = 0; x < Width; x += 0.005F)
{
    y2 = (float)Complex.Pow(Math.Sin(x), x).Real;

    g.DrawLine(pen, x1 * eF, y1 * eF + yEx, x * eF, y2 * eF + yEx);
    x1 = x;
    y1 = y2;
}
```

The result is this:

[image]

Comment: very nice. didn't know .net has Complex class for this.

Comment: Just Bravo, my friend. Really helpful. I wouldn't have guessed that C# has a way to handle this with Complex.Pow. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Validate your values for the `DrawLine`.

You do a check for the `Width` at the loop, but you do not validate your calculations before you call `DrawLine`. Here's an example without the draw:

```
float x1 = 0;
float y1 = 0;

float y2 = 0;

float yEx = 300;
float eF = 50;

const int width = 1024;
const int height = 1024;

for (float x = 0; x < width; x += 0.005F)
{
    y2 = (float)Math.Pow(Math.Sin(x) , x);

    var a = x1 * eF;
    var b = y1 * eF + yEx; 
    var c = x * eF;
    var d = y2 * eF + yEx;

    if(a < 0 || a >= width || b < 0 || b >= height || c < 0 || c >= width || d < 0 || d > height)
        Console.WriteLine("Snap! {0} | {1} | {2} | {3}", a, b, c, d);
    x1 = x;
    y1 = y2;
}
```

[Here's an online example](http://rextester.com/BFK67721)

GDI will not help you out when you try to draw off the canvas, in fact it will normally go boom. You should always limit the values to be within the height and width.

Here's some highlights of the example:

```
Snap! 1101,215 | NaN | 1101,465 | NaN
Snap! 1101,465 | NaN | 1101,715 | NaN
Snap! 1101,715 | NaN | 1101,965 | NaN
Snap! 1101,965 | NaN | 1102,215 | NaN
Snap! 1102,215 | NaN | 1102,465 | NaN
Snap! 1102,465 | NaN | 1102,715 | NaN
Snap! 1102,715 | NaN | 1102,965 | NaN
Snap! 1102,965 | NaN | 1103,215 | NaN
Snap! 1103,215 | NaN | 1103,465 | NaN
Snap! 1103,465 | NaN | 1103,715 | NaN
Snap! 1103,715 | NaN | 1103,965 | NaN
Snap! 1103,965 | NaN | 1104,215 | NaN
Snap! 1104,215 | NaN | 1104,465 | NaN
Snap! 1104,465 | NaN | 1104,715 | NaN
Snap! 1104,715 | NaN | 1104,965 | NaN
Snap! 1104,965 | NaN | 1105,215 | NaN
```

Comment: Replacing the interior of the for loop with `g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, -1, -1, 1200, 800);` (on a `Bitmap` with size 1024x768) runs just fine. I don't think that drawing off the edges of the canvas is the problem in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that [Math.Pow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) sometimes returns a float that is [not a number or NaN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single.nan(v=vs.110).aspx).  Specifically:

> x < 0 but not NegativeInfinity; y is not an integer, NegativeInfinity, or PositiveInfinity.  = NaN

Since Sin(x) will draw a curve that is both above and below 0, some of its values will be negative, thus the `Math.Pow` call will yield NaN, which of course cannot be drawn on Cartesian space.

I suggest you temporarily modify your code as follows: Wrap the draw call with a try block.

```
try
{
    g.DrawLine(pen, x1 * eF, y1 * eF + yEx, x * eF, y2 * eF + yEx);
}
catch {}  //Not usually a great idea to eat all exceptions, but for troubleshooting purposes this'll do
```

Then run your code and view the line.  The breaks in the line will tell you which parts of the domain/range are problematic.  Once you have a holistic view of the computational issues, you may be able to transform/map your Cartesian space into a domain where the overflows don't happen, e.g. by adding a constant to the result of the SIN function.

Comment: Using `NaN` as an input for a `Graphics.DrawX` method isn't going to work, but it also isn't going to throw an exception. It just does nothing.

Comment: Speaking of negatives, GDI will also tend to throw a Out of Memory exception when you pass in negative numbers. Those are fun debug times when you think you legitimately ran out of memory. ;)